# How to mock Azure ServiceBus Receiver in Python MagicMock

Tags: python, azure, unit-testing, pytest, azureservicebus

I'm using the [Python Azure ServiceBus package](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-servicebus/latest/azure.servicebus.html#azure.servicebus.ServiceBusReceiver) and have the following snippet of code:

```
# receiver.py

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("test")

def receive_message(
        connection_str,
        queue_name
) -> None:
    """
    Call Azure ServiceBus API to retrieve message from a queue
    """
    with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(
            connection_str, logging_enable=True
    ) as servicebus_client:

        with servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(
                queue_name=queue_name,
                max_wait_time=20,
                receive_mode=ServiceBusReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK,
        ) as receiver:
            for message in receiver:
                logger.debug(f"Received message {message}")
```

I'm attempting to write unit tests for this function, and want to be able to mock out the `recevier`. Here is my attempt at writing the unit test, which fails because I can't figure out how to get the test to enter the `for message in receiver` block.

```
# test_receiver.py

@patch("receiver.ServiceBusClient")
@patch("receiver.logger")
def test_receive_message(mock_logger, mock_svcbus_client):

    # Figure out how to mock
    mock_svcbus_client.from_connection_string.return_value.get_queue_receiver.return_value = iter(["message"])


    receive_message("mock_connection_str", "mock_q_name")
    
    # Assertion fails
    mock_logger.return_value.debug.assert_called_once()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `from mocks import MockReceivedMessage, MockReceiver` to mock the `receiver`

**Example 1:**

```
class MockReceivedMessage(ServiceBusReceivedMessage):
    def __init__(self, prevent_renew_lock=False, exception_on_renew_lock=False, **kwargs):
        self._lock_duration = kwargs.get("lock_duration", 2)
        self._raw_amqp_message = None
        self._received_timestamp_utc = utc_now()
        self.locked_until_utc = self._received_timestamp_utc + timedelta(seconds=self._lock_duration)
        self._settled = False
        self._receiver = MockReceiver()

        self._prevent_renew_lock = prevent_renew_lock
        self._exception_on_renew_lock = exception_on_renew_lock
```

**Example 2**:

```
 def test_queue_message_receive_and_delete(self, servicebus_namespace_connection_string, servicebus_queue, **kwargs):
        
        with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(
            servicebus_namespace_connection_string, logging_enable=False) as sb_client:
                
            with sb_client.get_queue_sender(servicebus_queue.name) as sender:
                message = ServiceBusMessage("Receive and delete test")
                sender.send_messages(message)
    
            with sb_client.get_queue_receiver(servicebus_queue.name,
                                                 receive_mode=ServiceBusReceiveMode.RECEIVE_AND_DELETE) as receiver:
                messages = receiver.receive_messages(max_wait_time=10)
                assert len(messages) == 1
                message = messages[0]
                print_message(_logger, message)
                with pytest.raises(ValueError):
                    receiver.complete_message(message)
                with pytest.raises(ValueError):
                    receiver.abandon_message(message)
                with pytest.raises(ValueError):
                    receiver.defer_message(message)
                with pytest.raises(ValueError):
                    receiver.dead_letter_message(message)
                with pytest.raises(ValueError):
                    receiver.renew_message_lock(message)
    
            time.sleep(10)
    
            with sb_client.get_queue_receiver(servicebus_queue.name) as receiver:
                messages = receiver.receive_messages(max_wait_time=10)
                for m in messages:
                    print_message(_logger, m)
                assert len(messages) == 0
```

You can refer to  [mocks.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/0320acedeeb8fd33034c9e37f9224218773b7880/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/tests/mocks.py)
and [test_queues.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/tests/test_queues.py)

If you still have doubt, You can open an issue on GitHub: [azure-sdk-for-python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues)